# Missing iPAD simulator data (its not in~ Application Support/iphone Simulator)

Tags: sqlite, xcode4.2

This question has been asked many times, but I still can't find the sqlite file and other files generated by xcode4.2 running the ipad 5.0 simulator.  I have looked in the suggested location:
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/X.X/Applications/APP_UUID/ but I have no "iPhone Simulator" folder in "Application Support".  In fact, I have searched my hard drive for an "iphone simulator" folder or "APP_UUID" and cannot find anything!  I also can't find any .sqlite files that seem related to my project.  The project itself uses core data and loads/unloads perfectly.  I'm not sure if it matters, but all the files for the project are stored in a dropbox folder not the typical location.  (The .sqlite files are not anywhere on dropbox either).

Fortunately, the ipad simulator option to delete/reset the data seems to work, but I'm going crazy looking for these files.  I'm not sure why Apple made these files so cryptic, but that is another debate.

thanks for putting up with this same question again!

Comment: You could put a NSLog with the DB-Pathname into the app in check /var/log/system.log, it should show the full path.